# Convert a document using ebproof to HTML?

Tags: tex4ht, pandoc, html, htlatex

I have a very simple document using ebproof that I'd like to render to both PDF and HTML:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{ x {:} \sigma \in \Gamma }
    \infer1[var]{ \Gamma \vdash x {:} \sigma}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

Right now, the PDF works perfectly, but the HTML from htlatex/tex4ht renders as

x:σ ∈ Γ __________ var Γ ⊢ x:σ

and HTML from pandoc renders as

1[var] x :

instead of

[image]

Is there an HTML conversion that can render this properly, or a way to configure one of the other tools to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the `prooftree` environment to produce image with `tex4ht`. It would be better to produce clean HTML or MathML code, of course, so I will try to look at this issue later.

Try the following configuration file, `mycfg.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ConfigureEnv{prooftree}{\Picture*{}}{\EndPicture}{}{}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `\Picture* ... \EndPicuture` command requests conversion of the contained code to image. It is inserted around the `prooftree` environment using `\ConfigureEnv` command.

Compile the document using

```
make4ht -c mycfg.cfg filename.tex
```

[make4ht](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/make4ht?lang=en) is build system for `tex4ht`, is it replacement for `htlatex` with much more features.

This is the result:

[image]