# ebproof undefined control sequence \hypo

Tags: undefined, proof-package

I'm trying to use the `ebproof` package with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{prooftree}
    \hypo{ x {:} \sigma \in \Gamma }
    \infer1[var]{ \Gamma \vdash x {:} \sigma}
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

(taken from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383114/))

However when I try to compile it to a pdf I get the following error:

```
$ pdflatex test.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9q> and hyphenation patterns for 81 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebproof/ebproof.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex)))) (./test.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \hypo 

l.8     \hypo
             { x {:} \sigma \in \Gamma }
? q
OK, entering \batchmode⏎
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong :/

I'm using TeX Live on Linux Mint 18.1 and it is updated to the latest version through Mint's package manager.

Comment: Your code runs through without problems on TeXLive2017 on MacOS. Your output shows `TeX Live 2015/Debian`. Are you sure that this is the latest version?

Comment: I guess what I meant to say was "the latest version of TeXLive that comes with Mint 18.1", which admittedly might not be recent enough.

Comment: This does seem like a strange error though, since the `ebproof.sty` file does exist on my computer, and it does contain the definition for `\hypo`.

Comment: Well, you might want to look through your `ebproof.sty` file and check if `\hypo` is defined there and/or use `texdoc ebproof` in order to see which commands are provided by your version.

Comment: Turns out the commands are uppercase in ebproof versions lower than 2.0. Thanks for your help! (If you want to post that as an answer I will accept it, otherwise I'll accept my answer in a couple of days.)

Comment: glad to hear. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Version 1.1 of the ebproof package (March 13, 2015) uses `\Hypo` and `\Infer` rather than `\hypo` and `\infer`. Thanks to marmot for suggesting that I used `texdoc ebproof`.

As a workaround I've added this to my preamble:

```
\newcommand\hypo{\Hypo}
\newcommand\infer{\Infer}
```

(This will make it easy to update to ebproof v2.0 or TeXLive 2017 in the future without breaking my LaTeX document.)

Alternatively installing TeXLive 2017 [from a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/a/955969) would fix the issue via version 2.0 of ebproof which uses lowercase commands. (I did not actually try this approach myself).